# How would I go about adding Unicode Emoticons into LateX?

Tags: xetex, pdftex, unicode

How would I go about adding the large range of emotions (                                                                                ) into LateX itself?

I tried using XeLatex but it just came up with each one with "??"

Comment: Well you need to get XeTeX to use a font which has these symbols. for example, many of your emoticons do not show up on my browser

Comment: Do you happen to know a font that would be suitable to do that? They show up on my El Capitan if that helps?

Comment: Many options; see, e.g., the [emoticons category on fontspace](http://www.fontspace.com/category/emoticons) or the [Dingbats > Various category on dafont](http://www.dafont.com/theme.php?cat=721). Not sure what you mean by 'I tried using XeLatex', however. What did you try? What font did you load? How did you input these emoticons?  These questions are best answered by providing a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)).

Answer (score 12):

I can get most of them e.g. with DejaVu Sans (but some are missing):

```
%compiled with lualatex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}

\begin{document}

How would I go about adding the large range of emotions (                                                                                ) into LateX itself

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can find fonts that support a symbol e.g. here http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f64c/fontsupport.htm

Answer (score 4):

After lot's of searching I managed to get full support with a twitter based emoji set from here:

https://github.com/alecjacobson/coloremoji.sty