# Insert an emoticon using xelatex

Tags: xetex, unicode

I would like to insert an emoticon (Unicode 10. code point 1F600) into my document. Mine just shows a tofu box.

Here is my failing example:

```
\documentclass[9pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[Latin,Greek,Emoticons]{ucharclasses}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\substitutefont{Times New Roman}
\setDefaultTransitions{\begingroup\substitutefont}{\endgroup}

\begin{document}

The standard
consists of various documents or charts that map \emph{code points} (hexadecimal
numbers such as \texttt{0048} or \texttt{1F600}) to glyphs (such as \texttt{H} or \texttt{}), and
names (\emph{LATIN CAPITAL H} and \emph{GRINNING FACE}). The code points and names are
unique, though many glyphs may look very similar.

\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be nice to add the error or why it failed, so people who don't have access to Latex software can guide you to the right direction.

Comment: You probably just need to load a font that supports this glyph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the answer here: [How would I go about adding Unicode Emoticons into LateX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304156/how-would-i-go-about-adding-unicode-emoticons-into-latex) "DejaVu Sans" font offers such characters.

You need some modifications like not adding the emoticon in '\texttt'

Full code:

```
\documentclass[9pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[Latin,Greek,Emoticons]{ucharclasses}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\mydef{DejaVu Sans}
\setDefaultTransitions{\mydef}{}
\newfontfamily\mynormal{Linux Libertine O}
\setTransitionsForLatin{\mynormal}{}
\newfontfamily\mygreek{GFS Artemisia} 
\setTransitionsForGreek{\mygreek}{}

\begin{document}

The standard
consists of various documents or charts that map \emph{code points} (hexadecimal
numbers such as \texttt{0048} or \texttt{1F600}) to glyphs (such as \texttt{H} or ), and
names (\emph{LATIN CAPITAL H} and \emph{GRINNING FACE}). The code points and names are
unique, though many glyphs may look very similar. Ελληνικά εδώ!

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Spoke too soon. My mono fonts are messed up now. Seems to be ignoring my `\setmonofont[Scale=0.9]{Source Code Pro}` in my `lstlisting` sections

Comment: If this doesn't solve your problem anymore, please update your question with the needed parts of code (or ask a new one).

Comment: It solves my original question. I asked about the other issue here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395948/lstlisting-confused-by-ucharclasses-monospace-code-and-unicode-emojis-with

Answer (score 0):

I'd also give a try to `coloremoji.sty` (Specifically [this fork](https://github.com/chardmeier/coloremoji.sty)). It is basically a map between every unicode emoji character found in your document and a database of PDFs per emoji. In comparison to [`xelatexemoji.sty`](https://github.com/mreq/xelatex-emoji), you don't have to create yourself the PDFs from a list of SVGs - the PDFs are bundled with the repository.