# `lstlisting` confused by `ucharclasses` (monospace code and unicode emojis) with xelatex

Tags: xetex, unicode, typewriter

I need to have Unicode emojis in text dealing with code and Unicode. When I include the `ucharclasses` and the correct incantation, I can get the Unicode emojis, but any monospaced text appears to revert to the default text (Notice the "brew install python3" and the code section)

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont[Scale=0.9]{Source Code Pro}
\usepackage[Latin,Greek,Emoticons]{ucharclasses}

\newfontfamily\mydef{DejaVu Sans}
\setDefaultTransitions{\mydef}{}
\newfontfamily\mynormal{Palatino}
\setTransitionsForLatin{\mynormal}{}

\usepackage{listings}
 \lstset{ %
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,        % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
    aboveskip=5pt,
    belowskip=5pt,
  }

\begin{document}

The standard
consists of various documents or charts that map \emph{code points} (hexadecimal
numbers such as \texttt{0048} or \texttt{1F600}) to glyphs (such as \texttt{H} or ), and
names (\emph{LATIN CAPITAL H} and \emph{GRINNING FACE}). The code points and names are
unique, though many glyphs may look very similar. it is a simple \texttt{brew install python3} away.

\begin{lstlisting}[xleftmargin=0em]
>>> type(value)
<class 'str'>
>>> value + other
'34'
\end{lstlisting}


\end{document}
```

[image: Emoji but no monospace]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's much safer to set the transitions to and from a specific block or class of blocks:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[Latin,Greek,Emoticons]{ucharclasses}
\usepackage{listings}

\setmainfont{Palatino}
\setmonofont[Scale=0.9]{Source Code Pro}

\newfontfamily\mydef{DejaVu Sans}

\setTransitionsFor{Emoticons}{\begingroup\mydef}{\endgroup}

 \lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    aboveskip=5pt,
    belowskip=5pt,
  }

\begin{document}

The standard
consists of various documents or charts that map \emph{code points} (hexadecimal
numbers such as \texttt{0048} or \texttt{1F600}) to glyphs (such as \texttt{H} or ), and
names (\emph{LATIN CAPITAL H} and \emph{GRINNING FACE}). The code points and names are
unique, though many glyphs may look very similar. it is a simple \texttt{brew install python3} away.

\begin{lstlisting}[xleftmargin=0em]
>>> type(value)
<class 'str'>
>>> value + other
'34'
\end{lstlisting}


\end{document}
```

[image]